# WPF ItemsControl Binding to UserControl

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, user-controls, itemscontrol

I have a WPF application where I need to do something like that :

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="lstProducts">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductName}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I set the ItemsSource in code like this : `lstProducts.ItemsSource = MyEFContext.Products;`

Up to now everything is working fine.  Now I want to use my own **UserControl** to display a product instead of the **TextBlock** like that.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="lstProducts">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <my:ProductItemCtl ProductName="{Binding ProductName}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In my userControl, I created a `DependencyProperty` like that (see below) where I set the `ProductName` in the `OnProductNameChanged` callback.

The `TextBlock` in my usercontrol is not updated when binding the `ItemsControl`, and the callback is not launched.

```
#region ProductName

        /// <summary>
        /// ProductName Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ProductNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ProductName", typeof(String), typeof(ProductItemCtl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("",
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnProductNameChanged)));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the ProductName property. This dependency property 
        /// indicates ....
        /// </summary>
        public String ProductName
        {
            get { return (String)GetValue(ProductNameProperty); }
            set {  SetValue(ProductNameProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the ProductName property.
        /// </summary>
        private static void OnProductNameChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProductItemCtl target = (ProductItemCtl)d;
            String oldProductName = (String)e.OldValue;
            String newProductName = target.ProductName;
            target.OnProductNameChanged(oldProductName, newProductName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides derived classes an opportunity to handle changes to the ProductName property.
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual void OnProductNameChanged(String oldProductName, String newProductName)
        {
            // Set Product Name in the display Here!
            this.txtProductName.Text = newProductName;
        }

        #endregion
```

Comment: Does adding Mode=TwoWay to your binding on your user control help? Also, why are you setting the text of your textbox in code (in OnProductNameChanged)? Why not bind it?

Comment: Doesn't the line `DependencyProperty.Register("ProductName", typeof(String), typeof(AchatItem)` should actually have `typeof(ProductItemCtl)` instead of `typeof(AchatItem)`?

Comment: No TwoWay does not change anything.  I simplified the code here just to isolate the problem.  In real need to do a lot more things than just setting the Text value.

Comment: Good call Lester, but  that's not the issue.  Leftovers from trying to simplify my example.  I modified my example code.  Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: Nope, It just never update my textbox.  the this.txtProductName.Text = newProductName; is never called

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me. You should make sure that you didn't drop the code that actually causes this problem when you simplified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but i can't write this as comment. What happens if you simplify your code like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ProductNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ProductName", typeof(string), typeof(ProductItemCtl), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty,
        (o, e) => ((ProductItemCtl)o).txtProductName.Text = (string)e.NewValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrrghhh got it... I had `this.ProductName = "";` in the constructor of my UserControl

I wasted so much time on this... And sorry for wasting all of yours.

Since I found out by trying your code Clemens I will mark your answer as "Answered".

thanks everyone.